# Cannot save the contents of a QGraphicsScene in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem, qsettings

I want my application to save the contents of my scene which contains graphics items in it and later be able to retrieve all those items(not as a QPixmap, but as actual individual items).
I have tried using Qsettings but get a QVariant error.
My code is:

```
QSettings settings("AdvProgLab","ERapp");
settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
settings.setValue("saved_scene",scene);      //Here, scene is a QGraphicsScene
settings.endGroup();
```

And the error which I am getting is:

> qvariant.h:471: error: ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’ is private
>        inline QVariant(void *) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
>               ^
>
> error: use of deleted function ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’

Can anybody please explain me where I am going wrong ?
Or is there any other way by which I can achieve this .

Thank You.

Comment: You can't convert QGraphicsScene to QVariant.

Comment: @MichaelO. then how can i save the contents of a scene if I want to ?

Comment: Save various parameters, such as position, size, angle etc.

Comment: @MichaelO. Saving various parameters , how will the scene know the type of item which it needs to retrieve ?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678877/save-load-items-from-a-qgraphicsscene